# How good, from an ethical, perspective is APA's "Critical Incidents Technique" to develop a code of ethics?

Tags: ethics, psychology

Here I am using good as acceptable or consistent from a philosophical ethics perspective. It strikes me that in order to confirm it they just made a survey of what scientists thought were ethical problems, summarized them and then pronounced them as their ethical principles (Goodwin, 2009).

> What is noteworthy about the Hobbs committee is that, in keeping with psychology’s penchant for relying on data before drawing conclusions, it **opted for
>   an empirical approach to forming the code**. Using a procedure called the critical
>   incidents technique, the committee surveyed the entire membership of the APA
>   (there were about 7,500 members then), asking them to provide examples of ‘‘incidents’’ of unethical conduct that they knew about firsthand and ‘‘to indicate what [they] perceived as being the ethical issue involved’’ (APA, 1953, p. vi). The request yielded over 1,000 replies.

Can ethics be developed in such a "scientific" way? For me I think this should be a work of philosophy, not science, but please illuminate me.

Thanks.

*References*

Goodwin, C. J. (2009). *Research in psychology: Methods and design.* (p.43) Hoboken, NJ: Wiley.

Comment: Can you please provide a reference to Goodwin (2009) cited in your question?

Comment: There are distinct TYPES of ethics.  Science involves what is often called descriptive ethics which reports the way things currently are -- NOT as ideal or as they Should BE.  Normative ethics is not part of science but philosophy.  Normative ethics expresses how things should be universally planet wide.  No committees or voting needed. Psychology is a science and in this context does not use normative ethics.  This is not part of Philosophy unfortunately.  It would be an error to think ethics is all the same.

Comment: Ethical rules can be developed in this way but it is not a scientific approach. It would be like having a vote on proton decay.